# Qt Creator "Item Couldn't be created"

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator, qtquick2

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnaOJ.png)

This is my first time installing Qt Creator. In Qt Creator "form editor" isn't showing anything but the text editor is working fine and the application is running properly. In the navigation menu (bottom left of the picture) there is a red line under 'Window' and a error sign before it. When I hover cursor, it shows "item couldn't be created". How can I solve it?